# How can I secure Front-End in a Vuejs SPA?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, single-page-application

I'm building a **SPA** using **Vuejs** and consuming **Laravel API's**, and users can have multiple roles, what is the best way to save token and user roles? as well as prevent users from knowing what the roles are?

There is one solution I know yet, which is to save them in **Cookies and LocalStorage**.
However, if someone knows my **LocalStorage key** for the roles and they were just like a normal user and changed it, so that they can see what **Admin Dashboard** looks like (Just the Front-End) and what Admin can see in the app.

How can I prevent them? and what are the best ways to secure SPA?

**Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never consider SPA frontend as "secure". If something is executed on browser it means it can be modified by user. It of course doesn't mean SPA is bad, no no, just it is not good solution for every project.
If You want to be sure that user will never see admin dashboard then it should be in separate bundle or even better - separate project.

Instead - consider migrating SPA to SSR (in Vue You can use Nuxt.js (https://nuxtjs.org/) for this).
Thank's to this user will receive only HTML response (just like in Laravel with Blade). Because of this You can authenticate user and check roles BEFORE user will receive any content (and block access to admin panel by that).

BUT - if You are using Laravel with Vue in same project (so Vue is initiated by Blade) this means You can just like in Nuxt check user before it will receive any content. Just make middleware for it. But it will help only by blocking entire page, and not for changing (in secure way) content on single page based on multiple roles. So again - You need SSR for that.

For any every solution I would suggest You to use new official library from Laravel - Sanctum (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum).

Comment: Okay, thank you chojnicki for the explanation, I'll learn Nuxt.js..
I use Vue and Laravel in the same project, but I don't use Blade, I just make a * Route so everything will be rendered at Vuejs.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel API use role and permission to check user is can do something.

Client save jwt token and use jwt to authen Laravel API. You will get user info in laravel side. Use user id check in role table.

Comment: I don't have problems in Backend, I'm confused only with the Front-End.

Comment: How about nuxt.js to server side rendering ?